# MSSQL server 2008 R2 can't store data in UTF-8

Tags: php, sql-server, iis-7

I have a working configuration:
TestLink 1.9.10 + PHP 5.4 + IIS 7 + MSSQL server 2008 R2
UTF8 data is inserted into Database with wrong encoding. 
Also i use SQLSRV and PDO_SQLSRV version 3.0.1
Tried to change varchar to nvarchar DBfield type. No result. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
Hi putting "N" prefix for each string value like:
insert into table(col1,col2) values(N'value1',N'value2');

and example of PHP:

<?php
//Returns records with Id#46 or first name starting with 'Mary'

$server = '127.0.0.1'; 
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sql_user', 'sql_user_pass'); 

//Select DB 
$dbn = 'dbName'; 
mssql_select_db($dbn); 

//input variables
$name='Mary%';
$id=46;

//necesssary for stored procedure
$params="@name varchar(50),@id int";
$paramslist="@name='$name%',@id='$id'";

$sql = "select FirstName,LastName,EmpId from employees where FirstName like  @name or EmpId = @id  " ;

$dbsql = "EXEC sp_executesql 
          N'$sql', 
          N'$params',
          $paramslist";

//important to have the "N'" !

$result=mssql_query($dbsql,$link);
?>
```

Comment: It helped to insert UTF8 data manualy to the database. But this solution doesn't fit me. Because I can't change the whole application php-code. Nevertheless thanks for help.

I found another solution of my problem:
I change the charset from UTF8 to WINDOWS-1251 everywhere.
So it helped.